# как выбрать текущий проект в vscode linux?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Всем привет) подскажите пожалуйста, как выбрать текущий проект в vscode linux?

Например вот у меня есть 4 проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу запустить через отладчик F5 например проект Basics или Variables как мне это сделать?
В данный момент все время запускаеться первый проект Numbers....если нажать F5 или ctr + F5.
Я только учусь сорян за глупый вопрос)

Comment: спасибо) немного ошибся)

Comment: Open folder - папка с нужным проектом. Не?

Comment: так то можно но не то) можно и через терменал)а я хотел бы чтобы при нажатие на F5 запускался выбраный мной проект) я нашел вариант через (run and debag) но хотелось чтонибудь по быстрей)

Comment: *"не то"* - это не объяснение. Вы что ли хотите несколько папок держать открытыми?